# Android Market, Order Cancellation Reason - You cancelled this order

Tags: android, google-play, cancellation

A couple of weeks ago i uploaded one of App which happens to be a widget. But from the time i uploaded it i have seen lots of cancellation. The only reason google gives me is this:

```
You cancelled this order. Reason: Other (describe below) Message sent to customer: Cancellation requested from phone.
```

I cant get heads or tail of it... Wat should i understand from this??? There are no feedback, neither any ratings... who is "YOU" here?? I suppose this is not a programming question but this has arised after a lot of programming... Did anyone else also get something like this from Google and know wat it exactly means?

Comment: You already asked it in android market's support page: http://www.google.co.uk/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=311f568ab9dc4e42&hl=en

Just wait for an answer there :)

Comment: ya but i have not got any replies till now... Do you know anything about this stuff??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got a near perfect answer and you can check [it out here](http://www.google.co.uk/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=311f568ab9dc4e42&hl=en)

Comment: That post is down. What was the answer?

Comment: It means the user requested a refund from their phone. However, google should change its messages, or this is a grammar error